# Unknown code from Transposing Coffee Script to Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, coffeescript

First off - I'm new to javascript, so please don't over estimate my ability - though, in the process of learning I have thrown myself in the deep end with a few examples; 'and until now, that's been working pretty well.'
The exception being, trying to implement some code to improve scrolling.

I came across Chistopher Pappas' code:
https://github.com/damassi/smooth-scroll-example/blob/master/src/scripts/views/ScrollView.coffee
[of which, he seemed to know what he was talking about] but it was in coffee script - so I thought I would try and transpose it: FAIL. So then I thought i'd look at what it compiled to at: https://smoothscroll.firebaseapp.com/ [and the crux of my question] and have gotten terribly confused with a binding and constructor function code [I will excuse/ignore what appears to be a library - perhaps require.js?? - that wraps around the code and won't work without it, I believe...truly have no idea what it is, or what it is doing].

Anyhow, can anyone tell me how I can go about removing *what I believe to be* superfluous 'coffee legacy' code referenced from the 'ScrollView' constructor [ __bind / __hasProp etc.] and what it is acutally achieveing in the first place [my confidence has been shot now, especailly with the __extends function?

The actual code works, but as you can see - compared to Chris' example - it appears much of this code is not needed.

```
    (function e(t, n, r) { function s(o, u) { if (!n[o]) { if (!t[o]) { var a = typeof require == "function" && require; if (!u && a) return a(o, !0); if (i) return i(o, !0); throw new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'") } var f = n[o] = { exports: {} }; t[o][0].call(f.exports, function (e) { var n = t[o][1][e]; return s(n ? n : e) }, f, f.exports, e, t, n, r) } return n[o].exports } var i = typeof require == "function" && require; for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++) s(r[o]); return s })(
        {
            1: [
        function(module) {

            $(document).ready(function() {
                return new ScrollView();
            });
/**
 * ScrollView illustrates the ability to intercept scroll events, pipe them through
 * an easing equasion, and then apply them to a container.  Useful in situations where
 * you would like to normalize scrolling across an unknown number of devices / platforms
 * and apply the result to a parallax container or typical webpage
 *
 * @author Christopher Pappas <chris@wintr.us>
 * @date   5.2.14
 */
            var ScrollView,
                __bind = function(fn, me) { return function() { return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
                __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
                __extends = function(child, parent) {
                    for (var key in parent) {
                        if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key];
                    }

                    function ctor() {
                        this.constructor = child;
                    }

                    ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
                    child.prototype = new ctor();
                    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;
                    return child;
                };


            ScrollView = (function(_super) {
                __extends(ScrollView, _super);

                function ScrollView() {
                    this.animationLoop = __bind(this.animationLoop, this);
                    this.onScroll = __bind(this.onScroll, this);
                    return ScrollView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
                }

                //The easing which should be applied to inner container
                ScrollView.prototype.FRICTION = .3;
                //Number of individual items which are created within the container
                ScrollView.prototype.NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = 60;
                //Class name of the parent container
                ScrollView.prototype.className = 'container';

                //The next, computed position which is constantly being updated
                //inside of the render loop
                ScrollView.prototype.nextPosition = 0;

                //The current scroll position, which is applied via the keyframe
                ScrollView.prototype.currentPosition = 0;

                //The container in which to ease the scroll
                ScrollView.prototype.$scrollContainer = null;

                ScrollView.prototype.initialize = function() {
                    return this.render();
                };


               /*
               # Render the view by creating some dummy content which is then appended
               # to the dom for the scroll engine to calculate against. 
               */
                ScrollView.prototype.render = function() {
                    var $html = this.$el.html("<div class=item><h1>Item 0</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 1</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 2</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 3</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 4</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 5</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 6</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 7</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 8</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 9</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 10</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 11</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 12</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 13</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 14</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 15</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 16</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 17</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 18</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 19</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 20</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 21</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 22</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 23</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 24</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 25</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 26</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 27</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 28</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 29</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 30</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 31</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 32</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 33</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 34</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 35</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 36</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 37</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 38</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 39</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 40</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 41</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 42</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 43</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 44</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 45</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 46</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 47</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 48</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 49</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 50</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 51</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 52</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 53</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 54</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 55</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 56</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 57</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 58</h1></div><div class=item><h1>Item 59</h1></div>");
                    $html.appendTo('body');

                    /*
                    # Set the height of the main container so inner scroll
                    # container, which is set to position:fixed, can still
                    # be tied to an actual scrollbar
                    */
                    var elementZ = this.$el.find('.scroll-container');
                    this.$scrollContainer = elementZ;

                    var height = this.$scrollContainer.height();
                    //height = 19296;
                    $('.container').height(height);
                    //this.$el.height(height);
                    this.addEventListeners();
                    return this.animationLoop();
                };

                /*  Bind Listener to 'onScroll' scroll event [v] */
                ScrollView.prototype.addEventListeners = function() {
                    return $(window).on('scroll', this.onScroll);
                };
                /*
               # Handler for scroll events received when the scroll bar changes its
               # current position
               */
                ScrollView.prototype.onScroll = function(event) {
                    var value = $(window).scrollTop();
                    return this.nextPosition = value;
                };

                /*
               # The animation loop constantly inspects the current position of the scrollbar
               # and pipes it through an easing equasion.  This normalizes the scroll across
               # all scroll devices and allows for smooth scroll abilities within a normal
               # or parallax environment
               */
                ScrollView.prototype.animationLoop = function() {
                    this.currentPosition += ~~(this.nextPosition - this.currentPosition) * this.FRICTION;
                    /*I believe TweenMax in from GreenSock Plugin*/
                    TweenMax.set(this.$scrollContainer, {
                        y: -this.currentPosition
                    });
                    return requestAnimationFrame(this.animationLoop);
                };

                return ScrollView;

            })(Backbone.View);

            module.exports = ScrollView;
        }
    ]

    ,
    2: []
}, {}, [1]);
```

Thanks for any help / suggestions in anticipation, Livy

**In response to DelightedD0D:** http://js2.coffee/ code

```
var ScrollView, template,
  bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; },
  extend = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; },
  hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

template = require('./scroll-template.hbs');

ScrollView = (function(superClass) {
  extend(ScrollView, superClass);

  function ScrollView() {
    this.animationLoop = bind(this.animationLoop, this);
    this.onScroll = bind(this.onScroll, this);
    return ScrollView.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

note: to avoid confusion, I removed the 'template' and injected the HTML itself, but as you can see - it's basically the same.

The constructor and superclass [inheritance?] really confuse me, let alone the top function "(function e(t, n, r) { function s(o, u)...etc.", but I better stay on topic. Thanks

**UPDATE**: *Firstly*: I believe the very first function, and the way the file is laid out - is due to "Browserify"
i.e: (function e(t, n, r) { function s(o, u) { if (!n[o]) { if (!...
From what I understand, "Browserify" is for basically bundling all your dependencies/packages etc., into one file - so theoretically, shouldn't I be able to remove the "Browserify" code, as long as I reference the dependant scripts before and ScrollView operations and have it still function -- and from the above 'Browserify' code, it appears it IS the only module anyway? (I'm aware the overall code depends on jQuery / TweenMax, and maybe others?)

*Secondly*: I'm not 100% convinced this was an intended jQuery plugin (admittedly, I've only been reading up on such for a brief moment), but as I can't find any evidence of such e.g. (function( $ ) {... $.fn.scrollView etc., - I believe it's not.  I do believe DelightedD0D is correct in saying the 'Coffee' generated script is required, but for being able to be callbacked from whom/what - i'm still clueless?

Comment: Have you tried a converter like http://js2.coffee/?

Comment: Yeah, I did, thanks **DelightedD0D** - it is 'almost' exactly the same - but I will edit my answer to show it; 'superclass' etc. as you will see.

Comment: None of the converted code is "superfluous coffee legacy code". This is a plugin and each part has a role to play. Your question seems to be quite broad and is not likely to elicit useful responses here on SO as the site is not really for this type of discussion. I would suggest searching for key words that you dont understand for example [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). Also,you should look into [Authoring jQuery Plugins ](http://ryanflorence.com/authoring-jquery-plugins-with-object-oriented-javascript/)

Comment: Wow! I think your above post 'is' basically the answer - I had no idea about extending jQuery with plugins [I assume this is what's happening, now] - scarily, this seems way beyond me. I was originally trying to dissect Chris's code to see how he improves scrolling, not create a plugin, so I could hopefully improve some scrolling issues of my own. Thanks a lot **DelightedD0D**, although it wasn't really the rabbit burrow I wanted ;)